# create view from multiple row into one row

Tags: sql, vb.net, view

i have two table; question and answer

question table

```
QuestionID QuestionText
1          Question1
2          Question2
3          Question3
```

answer table. where it has fk to question table and bit to determine whether the answer is right

```
answerID answer_question_id(fk) answertxt answer_isright
1          1                    answer1   1
2          1                    answer2   0
3          1                    answer3   0
4          2                    answer1   1
5          2                    answer2   0
6          2                    answer3   0
```

so how do i create view where the first column is the question and second,third and fourth column is the answers (randomly)?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: mssql 2008 @HamletHakobyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` to solve your problem:

```
SELECT questionText, [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY newid()) AnswerInQuestionID,
        answerTxt, 
        QuestionText
    FROM questions q
        JOIN answers a
            ON q.QuestionID=a.answer_question_id
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(answerTxt)
    FOR AnswerInQuestionID IN ([1], [2], [3] )
) as piv
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1739/1)**

Comment: Where is the problem? If you have 3 answers for each question it will work.

Comment: what if i dont want to random it?

Comment: @sheldon What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

next query

```
SELECT answerid, answer_question_id, answer_isright, 
row_number() over (partition by answer_question_id order by newid()) as rnum
from answers
```

will return you your answer table with extra column to represent what column that answer goes to. "order by newid()" is not part of a standard and is different for every database vendor.

```
answerId  .... rnum
1              1    
2              3
3              2    
4              3
5              1    
6              2
```

(rnums would be different for every execution)

then you use this query to move answers to different columns based on rnum

```
select answerid, ..., case when rnum = 1 then answertxt else null end co1, ...
```

this will move your text like this:

```
answerId  .... rnum ... col1,   col2   col3
1              1        text1   null   null
2              3        null    null   text2
3              2        null    text3  null
4              3        null    null   text4
5              1        text5   null   null
6              2        null    text6  null
```

then you need to group them:

```
select answer_question_id, .., max(col1), max(col2), max(col3) from prev_query
group by answer_question_id, ...
```

then you join with a questions to add question text