# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'table' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, arrays, vb.net

I'm creating multiple choice question system. So far i create these 4 tables and 1 view.

The tables are tblQuestion, tblAnswer, tblQuiz, tblResult and tblResultDetail. tblQuestion is to store the questions, tblAnswer to store the answers of the question,tblResult is to record for every user that answers the quiz, and store the users answers in TblResultDetails.

Based on the code below, the data is read from view. I use 1 , 2 , 3, 4 as it is the column name of the view. I did this to randomize the answers.

```vb
Sub soalan()
    conn.Open()
        Dim myArr(3) As String
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From view_Soalan Where QuestionID=@IdSoalan", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdSoalan", Counter)
        Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr1.Read() Then
        Me.lblSoalan.Text = dr1("QuestionTxt")
        Me.RadioButton1.Text = dr1("1")
        myArr(0) = dr1("1")
        Me.RadioButton2.Text = dr1("2")
        myArr(1) = dr1("2")
        Me.RadioButton3.Text = dr1("3")
        myArr(2) = dr1("3")
        Me.RadioButton4.Text = dr1("4")
        myArr(3) = dr1("4")

        Dim answerId As String

        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            answerId = dr1("1")


        ElseIf Me.RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            answerId = dr1("2")

        ElseIf Me.RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            answerId = dr1("3")

        ElseIf Me.RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            answerId = dr1("4")

        End If

        'Dim jawapan As Integer = CInt(answerId)
        Session("jaw") = answerId

    Else
        conn.Close()
        Counter += 1
        soalan()
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
Sub bersih()
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    RadioButton4.Checked = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    soalan()
End Sub
Sub masuk()
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmdGetId As New SqlCommand("Select MAX(ResultId) From TblResult", conn)
    cmdGetId.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim drBaca As SqlDataReader
    drBaca = cmdGetId.ExecuteReader
    While drBaca.Read
        Dim maxID As Integer = drBaca(0)
        Session("maximum") = maxID
    End While



    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand("Insert into TblResultDetail (ResultDetail_Result_Id,ResultDetail_Answer_Id) values ('" & Session("maximum") & "','" & Session("jaw") & "')", conn)
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I got error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'table' to data
>   type int.

at the cmdInsert command. I know that i cant insert the session("jaw") into table directly. So how to replace it?

Comment: you should use sql parameters rather than appending text.

Comment: tried it. i need help in conversion problem

Comment: First step is to use profiler to see exactly what SQl you are sending to the database. I think you will be surprised to find out what is being sent and knowing what exactly is wrong is halfway to how to fix.  The error indicates you are sending a text value to the insert for a integer field. Likely one of the parameters you are sending is not the correct one. Or you need to join to a lookup table to get the integer value for the text value your system has.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have store in some of this fields a wrong value.

use this

```
   Public Module MyExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function IsInteger(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Integer.TryParse(value, Nothing)
        End If
    End Function




<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToInteger(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    If value.IsInteger() Then
        Return Integer.Parse(value)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
   End Module
```

and then

`value.ToInteger()` <-- returns 0 if it is not an integer

There is another error in your code. You should use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery in the query that starts with

"*Select MAX(ResultId)....*"

```
 Dim cmdGetId As New SqlCommand("Select MAX(ResultId) From TblResult", conn)
 Dim maxID As Integer= cmdGetId.ExecuteScalar 
 Session("maximum") = maxID
```

**ExecuteScalar** is typically used when your query returns a single value.

**ExecuteNonQuery** is typically used for SQL statements without results (UPDATE, INSERT, etc.).

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: but there is no error at the session("maximum"). the only problem is at the session("jaw")

Comment: in session("maximum") you can set every type of variable, you are storing the wrong number. Try my solution

Comment: my solution resolve another problem in your code, now I update the solution to solve the other error

Comment: i'm sure i'm storing the correct number for session("maximum"). i've checked it. like i mentioned, the only problem is with the session("jaw") because it was retrieve from a view not from table

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery  Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected. maybe you have a progressive id. it's just a case that it is operating correctly.  Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are quoting integers:

> ... values ('" & Session("maximum") & "','"

Simply remove the quotes. Also you should user Parameters instead to prevent SQL Injection.

I.e.

```
 Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand("Insert into TblResultDetail (ResultDetail_Result_Id,ResultDetail_Answer_Id) values (@max, @jaw)", conn)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max", Session("maximum"))
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jaw", Session("jaw"))
```

Comment: yes. like i said the problem is with the session"jaw". i retrieve it from a view and the view only select the text part of the answer table not the id. i'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524484/create-view-from-multiple-row-into-one-row/23525742?noredirect=1#comment36088026_23525742) code

Comment: then you need to have the id come back in your view / query and set jaw correctly, this is debugging 101 type question.